# Hibernate locking rows when using entityManager.flush()

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a standard stack Spring / JPA / Hibernate / Oracle, and found out that when I manually control the flush during a transaction, all entities subject to this flush (because of dirty check mainly) are locked in database with a READ lock until the end of the transaction.

We are not using any read lock, we have some write locks but not for the transaction I am testing, and this transaction is not read-only.

Is this standard behavior? Can it be avoided?
On my application, I have a set of queries that are run in a single transaction, they are of any kind, deletion, insertion, and updates. I want to be sure my delete queries are run first, thus the manual flush I need after the delete queries, but I don't want them to be locked in database.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question because you have shown neither your code, nor the SQL that Hibernate sends to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not on Hibernate, it is done by Oracle.

> The purpose of a DML lock, also called a data lock, is to guarantee the integrity of data being accessed concurrently by multiple users.
> ...
> DML statements automatically acquire locks at both the table level and the row level.

**Chunked summary of Locks Obtained by DML Statements**

| SQL Statement | Row Locks | Table Lock Mode | RS | RX | S | SRX | X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *INSERT INTO `table` ...* | Yes | SX | Y | Y | N | N | N |
| *UPDATE `table` ...* | Yes | SX | Y | Y | N | N | N |
| *DELETE FROM `table` ...* | Yes | SX | Y | Y | N | N | N |

- **RS** - row share lock
- **RX** - row exclusive lock
- **S** - share table lock
- **SRX** - share row exclusive table lock
- **X** - exclusive table lock
- **SX** - subexclusive table lock (synonym for row exclusive lock)

Full documentation about Automatic Locks are available at:

- [Release 21c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Automatic-and-Manual-Locking-Mechanisms-During-SQL-Operations.html#GUID-0304C4AA-BD28-4C2A-B7F5-267532FB9499)
- [Release 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_locks001.htm#SQLRF55502)